# Starting a Heroku worker dyno when someone is on site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, worker

In order get more bang for my buck, I am using the workless gem to dynamically start and stop my worker dyno when a job is created. I find that starting the dyno takes a bit too long to start up. Is there any way to have the dyno spin up as soon as someone gets on my homepage?

Comment: You could use something like https://uptimerobot.com to ping the server frequently (every 5 minutes) and that way keep it up all the time.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy but thats excatly what he does not want.

Comment: @nikorablin how many worker dynos do you need?

Comment: @eceeb Currently just one. Will probably scale up in the future.

Comment: As long as you need only one worker, you can put this worker on another app. Comsuming the free 750 hours. While having your web dyno again on another app. The dynos still can share the same resources e.g. database.

Comment: @eceeb Thats actually a great suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku is introducing new Dyno types.
If you use the new type "free" you can have a web Dyno and a worker Dyno on one app for free.
 If your web Dyno goes to sleep, your worker Dyno will also sleep. As soon as a new request comes to your web Dyno your worker Dyno will also wake up. That's likely what you have described in your scenario.
However a free Dyno must sleep at least 6 hours a day!
Also Heroku will migrate 1x Dyno apps to the "free" plan on 1. July 2015.